# Does collecting keys and dogtags have any purpose other than Trophies?

Tags: crysis-2

Is there a specific reason to collect all of these car keys, or all of the dog tags? To put it simply, are these only in the game for those try-hard gamers that think they have to get everything in a game in order to actually beat it? (No offense to anyone)

Answer (score 2):

**Dog tags** in Crysis 2 multiplayer serve two functions:

- They serve as a player icon for the player profile.As players
  progress through the game and multiplayer, they can unlock new dog
  tags to use.
- They are dropped by players upon death and can be collected by the player who killed them. Collecting dog tags unlocks support-measures such as the [Orbital Strike](http://crysis.wikia.com/wiki/Orbital_Strike).

**Souvenirs**

- Are fun to be found since they look cool.
- Unlock the “The Tourist” achievement (15G) or trophy (Bronze)."Find all New York Souvenirs in the Single Player Campaign".

**e-mails** only give you more detail about what is happening as you play the story.

**Vehicle keys** to my knowledge don't give you anything except the reason to play game once more to find all of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no benefit. They're are simply there as collectables.